# Connecting C# Console Application to a Web API to Update DB

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am really new to the concept of RESTful Web APIs, please do not go hard on me but I just really cannot think a way of it.

So basically, what I cannot find a solution for that I cannot find a way to make my console application works without my manuel 'start' command so that DB can stay up to date so that in the meanwhile API would only be responsible for getting the data from DB or other CRUD operations.

I had a console application which can parse data from a website and store the necessary values to the database. Then in the same solution, I also created a Web API - MVC project and wrote CRUD operations for all entity data types. They both works without any problem, however unless I manually make the console application to run the code and update the DB, DB has old values so the get operations ended up with wrong values.

All I wanted to do is to somehow run the console application's code (might be at certain times) so that the DB can stay up to date.

Hope I did not ask in a confusing but if I do it is because I cannot figure it out and cannot understand the process.

Appreciate if someone can briefly explain me what I have to do.

Thanks !

Comment: Sorry you can only ask about specific problems.  This is way too broad.  Try it yourself and ask questions about any actual problems you run into along the way.

Comment: How is it too broad? I wanted to make work my console application at certain times if it is okay so that DB can stay up to date

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for.  You need it to run every so many minutes.  Use windows scheduler: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Thanks! Let me take a look at it, sounds like the answer I am seeking for

Comment: My DB is local right now so I think what you suggest me most probably will work, @Kevin . So I will go with it. In fact, if you turn it to an answer I can accept. However, may I ask you what if my DB was on cloud, like azure. How will I then make it work?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where your db is.  It's where the console app is.  To answer your question about that.  Azure (I'm assume Amazon too) have a scheduler service which will do the same thing.

Comment: I see, that is great! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking really isn't a programming question per se, but more of a scheduling question.  You could turn your code into a [service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) and install it, but that is really overkill for what you need.  (Some people would argue that a windows service isn't appropriate for this since all it does is run at scheduled times and not wait to intercept information, but that is a whole other discussion).

What you need is a Scheduled Task in Windows: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7